# Launchpad Single Sign On

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, login

There was a link on a popular Facebook 'Ubuntu fan page' to the site today. Somebody commented to ask "Why can not use Launchpad username and password??".

Of course you can use your launchpad account - by entering your launchpad profile URL in the OpenID login – e.g. https://launchpad.net/~fred-bloggs

In fact we could use the Launchpad Single Sign On (aka Launchpad sign on) as used by most official Ubuntu webpages, because Launchpad Single Sign On is as I understand it, effectively an OpenID provider.

It would be wonderful if by the Ubuntu Stack Exchange official launch there was an obvious option on the login page to use this 'standard Ubuntu account'. Without this, we may alienate many potential users of the site.

Edit: I asked about this at [Meta StackOverflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61456/custom-openid-for-sites)

Comment: Is there a way to ask SE folks on how to help us out with this? I think we're having a chicken and the egg problem because Ubuntu contributors have lp id's and using launchpad.net/~username is not obvious.

Comment: That's what I was hoping to achieve by opening this question. If we can all vote it up to show SE it's important to us that would be useful.

I think it should be possible to use Launchpad in the same was Google, Yahoo and Facebook are shown on the login screen - you click a 'launchpad' button and the cleverness somehow finds your openID url for you.

Comment: Bumpity Bumpity Bump!

Answer (score 4):

I think adding "Launchpad" as one of the big icons (next to Google icon) for the log in will help alleviate this and will likely be the best option. Once that option is clicked it should prompt for their launchpad username.

Comment: What about Ubuntu single sign on https://login.ubuntu.com/?

Comment: I believe LaunchPad uses the same thing that login.ubuntu.com does: https://launchpad.net/canonical-identity-provider

Comment: Are they the same database of users or just using the same software at different URLs? It doesn't look like they are the same service.

Comment: @moberley According to comments on this post: http://meta.ubuntu.stackexchange.com/questions/222/ubuntu-one-integration-or-something/223#223 they are the same.

Comment: Thanks, I decided to ask a question about that specifically because I've always been unsure about the relationship between the two services. http://ubuntu.stackexchange.com/questions/2786/what-is-the-relationship-between-ubuntu-single-sign-on-and-launchpad-login-servic

Answer (score 4):

Launchpad's OpenID auth works a little like Google's implementation, insofar as you don't enter your Launchpad username on the client site, but instead the [Launchpad Login Service](http://login.launchpad.net) 
returns a username.

Getting it added to the list should be straightforward, and is a great idea.

Answer (score 2):

This has been implemented as noted by Jeff on [Meta StackOverflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61456/custom-openid-for-sites/67221#67221)

Answer (score 1):

The LP login should be replaced by Ubuntu SSO (Single Sign On) as the latter service will replace the former one.

Source: https://login.ubuntu.com/+description and https://login.ubuntu.com/+faq

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to form the OpenID url:

```
launchpad.net/~your_username_goes_here
```