# Ubuntu One Integration? Or something...

Tags: feature-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Launchpad Single Sign On](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/209/launchpad-single-sign-on)

https://one.ubuntu.com/

I like that the "Ubuntu One" cloud account goes hand in hand with the operating system, and now there's a music store... It seems like it has potential to be *the* online account to be associated with an Ubuntu user, in his capacity as an Ubuntu user. I think that potential could be well approached if there was a way to use your Ubuntu One account on these forums. I'm not sure how exactly they would be integrated... I just think that they can be, to some greater end.

Granted, I can always just use my Google account or Facebook account... Maybe Canonical can start pulling together a greater online social-media-style presence?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay... It hasn't really been answered per se, but... The issue is resolved I suppose. Thanks, guys, for helping me figure it out.

Can this thread be merged into the launchpad one? or... what?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is much (any?) scope for this site to be part of Ubuntu One itself. However we could provide the ability to use the same username and password as is used for Ubuntu One, Launchpad, the forums, etc: see [my question on Launchpad Single Sign On](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/209/launchpad-single-sign-on).

Comment: I meant Ubuntu single sign on, and I just guess I started talking about Ubuntu One for some reason. I had no idea that Launchpad was part of the Ubuntu Single Sign On thing. So, yeah, I guess we're on the same page.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean by integration, that you can use your single login with ubuntu's launchpad account, please look at [this question](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/209/launchpad-single-sign-on).

Comment: Sorry, I was talking about https://one.ubuntu.com/. I'm not really sure what launchpad is...

Comment: I think he was talking about https://login.ubuntu.com/. According to the folks I've talked to in `#launchpad` on `irc.freenode.net`, it and the Launchpad Login Service are the same internally.

Comment: Yeah, that's it. I thought "One" was the branding effort for the Ubuntu single-sign on, starting with the cloud service. But, yeah, login.ubuntu.com sounds right.

Comment: You might want to mark my bug report as affecting you: https://bugs.launchpad.net/canonical-identity-provider/+bug/626445